# Flutter apk build apk in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I have Flutter project that splits env like dev,uat.
I was build with command line "flutter build apk --target lib/main_dev.dart" in vscode.
I just tried to move to Android Studio.
I can set run target to develop it great but i try to set build target but it can't.
How can I do that in Android Studio (without using command flutter build)?

Answer (score 0):

**Build -> Flutter -> Build Apk**

[image]

Comment: Can I set build target file ?

Comment: @BossOffice set build target file for what? file name or other things?